# Apache webserver not able to connect to Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have configured Apache Httpd and Tomcat on my local system, by referring to this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/white-papers/load-balancing-and-scalability-via-tomcat-clusters.htm. I was trying to achive load balancing, but the connection between the webserver and the Tomcat server does not work:

In `workers.properties` file

```
workers.tomcat_home=D:/Installed/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
workers.java_home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

In `httpd.conf` file

```
# Path to workers.properties
JkWorkersFile D:/Installed/Apache24/conf/workers.properties
# Path to jk logs
JkLogFile D:/Installed/Apache24/logs/mod_jk.log
# Jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel info
# Jk log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
# JkOptions for forwarding
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkMount /BalServers worker1
JkMount /BalServers/* worker1
```

I have placed `mod_jk.so` file in modules folder.

My webserver is started and running (have tried with `http://localhost` URL, which shows me Apache home page). Tomcat server also works and is able to fetch `http://localhost:8080/BalServers/` URL. But when I try `http://localhost/BalServers/` URL, nothing is showing up, not even 404 status page.

Please let me know is any other configurations required?

Here is my `server.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

     <Engine jvmRoute="worker1" defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Is your tomcat server.xml configured correctly? Post server.xml of tomcat. Also try `JkMount / worker1` and check whether redirection works correctly then.

Comment: And for `JkMount / worker1` also not working.

Comment: Do I need to configure `VirtualHost` tag in `httpd.conf` file? I am using default `localhost` so I this this might not the issue.

Comment: i personally prefer mod_proxy so I know little about ajp but perhaps you are mixing mod_jk and ajp configuration ? Do you need to tell that tomcat runs on 8080 or is ajp able to detect this by other means ?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the version of both Apache and tomcat

Comment: Want to show that Tomcat is running on 8009 ajp port. I am using Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 7

Comment: I am trying run this Apache on Windows system. Is any extra conf required for Apache? is `modules/mod_jk.so` file will work for Windows Apache?

Comment: Off-topic, as is the question, but I *strongly* recommend you use mod_ajp instead of mod_jk. It works just as well and is ten times easier to configure.

Comment: What does logs/mod_jk.log  tell you?

Comment: ere is the last line from log file `[6592:6596] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3383): mod_jk/1.2.40 initialized`

Comment: You need to post the jk part of your httpd.conf, as below.

Comment: Edited question for `http.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit*** - You have not loaded workers.properties file in your httpd.conf. Also, it will be better if you switch on logging and monitor the modjk logs to see where the error is being thrown at.

This is the template you can follow for a successful mod_jk based load balancing.

> httpd.conf

```
LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so

# This is missing in your httpd.conf
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties  
JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log  
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "  
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories  
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"

#Use multiple context roots if necessary. But I follow the below.
JkMount  /* balancer
```

If you want a VirtualHost to be configured, wrap this inside a `<VirtualHost *:80>` or so

And then the workers.properties below

```
worker.list=balancer

worker.worker1.type=ajp13  
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=172.16.2.31

worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.port=8009
worker.worker2.host=172.16.2.42  


worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.method=B
worker.worker2.lbfactor=1
worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
#If sticky session is required
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=True
```

Have a look at these links

[Tomcat Server Configuration Doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/ajp.html)

[Mulesoft Tutorial](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/apache-tomcat-mod-jk-connector-configuration)

[Apache Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html)

Comment: Load balancing is next part. First my Apache is not able to talk with Tomcat server. And this is what I asked for.

Comment: You have not loaded your workers.properties in httpd.conf, AFAIS

Comment: It's there. I just forgot to add that line in above question.